# Spring filter collection first and then apply pagination

Tags: spring, pagination, spring-data

I have following code in my Spring RestController

```
Page<Message> messages = messagesRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id")));
return messages.getContent().stream().filter(Message::isPublished).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would like to apply the filter on my collection first (only get the published messages) and then apply a PageRequest on it.  How can I do that? Currently it is the other way around which does not return the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) that will return only published messages. Something like this:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {

    Page<Message> findByPublishedIsTrue(Pageable pageable);
}
```

[Supported query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords).